# awk - merge data and assign values based on matches

Tags: bash, awk, merge, match

I'm trying to create a file by merging all of the data from one file and part of the data from the second file combined with part of the data from the first file (assigned based on matches in column 1 of each file).  Column 1 of file1 may have multiple entries.  Column 1 of file2 may have zero, one, or multiple entries that match file1.  All of the records in file1 need to be present in the output file whether a match exists in file2 or not.  Wherever a match exists, an entry needs to be created that includes column 1 from file2 merged with column 2 from file1.

file1:

```
1000000001 3B413B9E9BD9E72DF10CE754F386B073
1000000001 70366A2BA2D0476FB587FBFE0904E891
1000000003 D9F5F4F8EC337F76CCE3C34AF33F5F4B
1000000004 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000000004 18FEA2F7BEF0FB4A67D2D2DDA3560B80
1000000007 3B413B9E9BD9E72DF10CE754F386B073
1000000008 4544AE8958411CC2CF541C0054EAFCB0
1000000013 566D29AC189E1C24D0E5DE46DCA14752
```

file2:

```
1000000002 1000010051
1000000002 1000000006
1000000002 1000010073
1000000004 1000000879
1000000004 1000018525
1000000004 1000000595
1000000004 1000001943
1000000004 1000001772
1000000004 1000001770
1000000010 1000000167
1000000010 1000001495
1000000013 1000016156
1000000013 1000000484
1000000013 1000000454
```

desired output (i don't care about sorting at this point - it can be handled later):

```
1000000001 3B413B9E9BD9E72DF10CE754F386B073
1000000001 70366A2BA2D0476FB587FBFE0904E891
1000000003 D9F5F4F8EC337F76CCE3C34AF33F5F4B
1000000004 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000000879 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000018525 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000000595 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000001943 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000001772 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000000004 18FEA2F7BEF0FB4A67D2D2DDA3560B80
1000000879 18FEA2F7BEF0FB4A67D2D2DDA3560B80
1000018525 18FEA2F7BEF0FB4A67D2D2DDA3560B80
1000000595 18FEA2F7BEF0FB4A67D2D2DDA3560B80
1000001943 18FEA2F7BEF0FB4A67D2D2DDA3560B80
1000001772 18FEA2F7BEF0FB4A67D2D2DDA3560B80
1000001770 18FEA2F7BEF0FB4A67D2D2DDA3560B80
1000000007 3B413B9E9BD9E72DF10CE754F386B073
1000000008 4544AE8958411CC2CF541C0054EAFCB0
1000000013 566D29AC189E1C24D0E5DE46DCA14752
1000016156 566D29AC189E1C24D0E5DE46DCA14752
1000000484 566D29AC189E1C24D0E5DE46DCA14752
1000000454 566D29AC189E1C24D0E5DE46DCA14752
```

I thought I had this with the following awk statement:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in a) {print $2,a[$1]}' file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
```

it seems that multiple entries got dropped, and also the data held some non-printing records when viewed on unix (only saw the longer string of file1 Column 2), but when opened in Notepad on windows, there were two rows for each record and two columns in every other row.  Thanks for any help you can provide!!

Comment: In your opening paragraph, I think it should be "...includes column **2** from file2 merged with column 2 from file1."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this produces the output you want:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;print;next}{for(i in a)if(a[i]==$1)print $2,i}' file1 file2
1000000001 3B413B9E9BD9E72DF10CE754F386B073
1000000001 70366A2BA2D0476FB587FBFE0904E891
1000000003 D9F5F4F8EC337F76CCE3C34AF33F5F4B
1000000004 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000000004 18FEA2F7BEF0FB4A67D2D2DDA3560B80
1000000007 3B413B9E9BD9E72DF10CE754F386B073
1000000008 4544AE8958411CC2CF541C0054EAFCB0
1000000013 566D29AC189E1C24D0E5DE46DCA14752
1000000879 18FEA2F7BEF0FB4A67D2D2DDA3560B80
1000000879 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000018525 18FEA2F7BEF0FB4A67D2D2DDA3560B80
1000018525 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000000595 18FEA2F7BEF0FB4A67D2D2DDA3560B80
1000000595 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000001943 18FEA2F7BEF0FB4A67D2D2DDA3560B80
1000001943 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000001772 18FEA2F7BEF0FB4A67D2D2DDA3560B80
1000001772 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000001770 18FEA2F7BEF0FB4A67D2D2DDA3560B80
1000001770 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000016156 566D29AC189E1C24D0E5DE46DCA14752
1000000484 566D29AC189E1C24D0E5DE46DCA14752
1000000454 566D29AC189E1C24D0E5DE46DCA14752
```

Print every line in the first file and store the key-value pair. For every line in the second file, loop through the array `a` and print all the matches from the first file for the first column.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the response, but the output is missing the following lines (this is where there were multiple entries in file1 for:
1000000004 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000000004 18FEA2F7BEF0FB4A67D2D2DDA3560B80)

missing records in desired output:
1000000879 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000018525 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000000595 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000001943 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D
1000001772 AE160D7D81E725556FAFD105F302D51D

Comment: @user4735294 I have updated my answer to deal with duplicates in the first column of the first file. I believe it produces the desired output now.

Comment: hello again, I was wondering if there is a buffer limit or some other awk limitation; I am running this against larger files and it seems that many entries are not making it into the output file.  file1 contains about 730 lines, file2 contains about 1700 lines.  My output file should have about 2000 lines, I am getting only about 1000.

Comment: @user4735294 these sizes don't sound big enough to run into any problems with memory limits, I guess the problem might lie with the format of the data.

Comment: thanks for your response regarding memory, I will continue looking at the data.

Comment: I've spent a day on this and ended up breaking file1 into smaller and smaller files using split.  The worst part is, the missing entries appear random, as in, many entries appear before and after as expected.  When file1 contains 25 lines, I have missing entries.  At 15 lines, I have all the entries expected.  At this point I am looking at splitting my file of ~730 lines into 50 files and running the awk statement against each, then appending to an output file.  Is there a better way?

Comment: @user4735294 if you update your question to provide a failing test case, along with the desired output, then I can take a look